# Emacs completion: autocomplete or company?

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

I'm new to emacs and I find it hard to make decisions on which extension to choose. Too many choices I say. The same pattern is true when I first started to use linux (choosing a distro, choosing packages to install, etc.)

I'm now faced with the dilemma of choosing between autocomplete and company. Both are emacs extensions that provide completion mechanisms for emacs. I may decide to use autocomplete because I think it's much more mature, and because of AutoJavaComplete which requires autocomplete. However, company mode also seems to be good, and some users report that it's much better than autocomplete. It lacks documentation though, which I rather find daunting.

Basically, I just want "intellisensy" completion when writing code. Which among the two is a better choice for this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can [feed company backends to auto-complete](https://github.com/buzztaiki/auto-complete/raw/master/ac-company.el), and the compatibility is probably possible in the reverse direction too - so your choice may not be too critical.

What comes out of discussions at the emacs wiki is that [CompanyMode is older](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/emacs-en/CompanyMode#toc9), and there is at least one [mention of bugs in favor of auto-complete](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoComplete#toc6). Indeed, it seems auto-conplete is what the cool kids are using these days, and [repository on github](https://github.com/auto-complete/auto-complete) shows active development. The [latest version of company](http://nschum.de/src/emacs/company-mode/), on the other hand, is nearly 11 months old.

Comment: FYI auto-complete repository is here: https://github.com/auto-complete/auto-complete.  The one mentioned by @huitseeker is the old repository.  auto-complete is maintained by a team now.

Comment: Nowadays `company-mode` is much better designed & maintained.

Comment: @Silex can `company-mode` show the doc of the function during the auto-completion

Answer (score 46):

The latest [company-mode](http://company-mode.github.com/) release is 12 hours old as I'm writing this. Recent work focused on bugfixing, as well as some nice new features.

I encourage you to try it, I think it provides better user experience than `auto-complete`.

Comment: Are you the current company-mode maintainer? ;)

Comment: Company seems to be gaining more ground recently. I'm going to give it a shot :)

Comment: Is there any support for fuzzy matching? I'm trying to use company with irony-mode and I can't get it woring :(

Comment: @redobot Currently, it's up to each individual backend.

Comment: I see, by now I'm using M-C-s. Is there some eas way to "automatically" enable this behavior (searching) when showing up the pop-up with the choices? that would solve the issue for me. I'm not a lisp expert so I can't do it myself.

Comment: @redobot You could define a new command which would enter completion and enable search mode. But you'll have to know a bit of Lisp to do that.

Comment: @Dmitry Ok, I'll try to do it. Thanks for the support and for the awesome company mode :)